# Integration true or false with brief explanation

Tags: integration

> For an integrable function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, if $\int_a^bf(x)dx>0$, then $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.

In my practise homework, the only question I don't know what to do for is this, I have tried a ton of scenarios to try and prove it's false but to no avail, how do i prove it's true (if it is)?

Comment: Well, can you come up with a function that has a positive integral on, say, $[0,1]$ but which takes some negative values there?  Remember, to disprove a conjecture you only need one counterexample.

Comment: Think about functions that are very positive most of the time but slightly negative in a small region.

Comment: Can I use cos(x) as the function and the interval [pie/2,-pie] as I can sub in -pie into cos to prove that its not always positive

Comment: Well, that;s an unusual interval (normally writing $[a,b]$ implies $a≤b$).  But if you write $[\-pi,\frac {\pi}2]$ your example works.  More simply, though, try $f(x)=100x-1$ on $[0,1]$.  Or, if you don't require continuity, let $f(x)=1$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=-1$.

Comment: Perhaps try a piecewise function?

Answer (score 0):

No, the property is not true. You may try with a step function:
$$f(x):=\begin{cases}
-1 & x\in [a,(a+b)/2],\\
2 & x\in ((a+b)/2,b].
\end{cases}$$
Then
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=-\frac{b-a}{2}+ 2\frac{b-a}{2}=\frac{b-a}{2}>0.$$
If you want a continuous function, try with a linear function $f$  such that $f(a)=-1$ and the value $f(b)$ is some positive number sufficiently large. For example 
$$f(x)=\frac{3(x-a)}{b-a}-1$$
What is its integral over $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** You can change the value of a function $f$ at a point $c\in[a,b]$ without changing the value of the integral over that interval.

Comment: If $f(x)>0 \forall x \in [a,b]$, wouldn't changing any point negative cause $f$ to be non-continuous on the interval $[a,b]$?

Comment: @ rb612 The function is assumed to be integrable (and not hence is not necesarily continuous)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: How about a function that starts at $f(0) = 0$, is positive over a certain interval, and then dips down below the $x$-axis and becomes negative? For example, $f(x)=\sin(x)$.

Now what happens if you compute $\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\ dx$?

What happens if you compute $\int_{0}^{\pi+0.1} f(x)\ dx$? What can you say about the sign of that? How about the sign of $f(x)$ along the interval?